# linux id and setuid/setgid

Tags: linux, setuid

Is there a simple way to see the real,effective and saved UID and GID for a running process?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ps` with either `U`, `G` (real) `g`, `u` (effective)?

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick read of the man page for ps. 
The following worked for me:

```
ps axo pid,ruid,euid,fuid,rgid,egid,fgid,ucmd | more
```

Answer (score 1):

The /proc filesystem contains this information:

/proc/PID/status